# How does this function fminunc(@(​t)(costFun​ction(t, X, y, lambda)), startingTheta, options) work?

Tags: matlab, function, machine-learning, parameters, logistic-regression

I've used just about every resource i could find and still haven't found a concrete answer to the question I'm asking. Here's the code in question

```
    X = data(:, 1:2);
    y = data(:,3);
    X = [ones(m, 1) X];
    startingTheta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
    lambda = 0;
    % Set options for fminunc, maximum iterations allowed is 500
    options = optimset('MaxIter', 500);
    % fminunc()
    % Optimization function that finds the min point of cost function J
    fprintf('Run fminunc');
    [theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y, lambda)), startingTheta, options);
    fprintf('Done \n');
    fprintf('Theta: %f \n', theta);
    fprintf('Cost at theta found by fminunc: %f\n', cost);
```

How does this function work? Nowhere in the code is t defined. What value is being passed into the parameters t, X, y. I came across this answer

```
X = 1; y = 1; % Defining variables which aren't passed into the costFunction          
% but which must exist for the next line to pass them as anything!
f = @(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)); % Explicitly define costFunction as a function of t alone
[theta, cost] = fminunc(f, 0, options);
```

but it really only confused me more. X and y are being defined only to be not passed into the costFunction. t isn't defined anywhere! What values exactly are being passed into these parameters? The code works, I just want to know how/why?

Comment: What language is this (looks like Matlab or Octave)? Please add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Matlab, sorry about that.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/520975-how-does-theta-cost-fminunc-t-costfunction-t-x-y-lambda-startingtheta-options-work#answer_428633)